# how do I get locale code from language code in PHP

Tags: php, localization, locale

Basically I have a lot of language codes `it, en, en-GB, de, de-CH, and so on...` and from these I need to get a full locale code `format: LANGCODE-COUNTRYCODE` with the default country of the language if the country code is not already specified.

An example of what I mean/need:

```
INPUT      OUTPUT  

it     ->  it-IT  
it-IT  ->  it-IT  
en-GB  ->  en-GB  
en     ->  en-US  
es-AR  ->  es-AR   
es-MX  ->  es-MX 
es     ->  es-ES
```

is there any library I'm unaware of or a simple way of achieving this in PHP?

I've tried finding solutions on google a lot but either it doesn't exist or I'm just using the wrong keywords...
Do I really have to make a manual array of this by hand? there must be a better way, I'm sure!

Comment: You need to decide what combinations you're going to support. There are dozens of locale codes for English - far more than you might anticipate. A complete table is hundreds of entries long. Note that es-BR is likely to be used less than pt-BR: Brazil is a Portuguese-speaking nation.

Comment: oh no I don't need the full table, only the "default" one: for english is US, for italian is IT, for spanish is Spain, for portuguese is Portugal and so on.... Does it make more sense now? I only need to get the default Country code for a particular language when the country code is not specified...

Comment: Why is Spain the default country for Spanish and United States the default for English, what are the rules?

Comment: As above...I don't think there is any common agreeement on what is the "default" for any given language, you'll probably need to define that yourself.

Comment: Well, italian can be it-IT and it-CH but it most definitely is it-IT by default. with English en-US is the default with any program you install, spanish is originally from spain, all others are kinda derivatives...  I have a scenario where I always need a lang and country specified. I have languages where if it's Argentian Spanish it is 'es-AR', but if it's just spanish it's only 'es'. in these cases I need to fall back on a "default" country... I guess I'll have to make my own list though, not what I hoped for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [iso.org](https://www.iso.org/home.html) and [localeplanet.com](https://www.localeplanet.com/) plus some good old googling and a lot of elbow grease, I came up with this list below.
It might not be perfect, but it will do the job for me... I hope it can be of help to others!

```
<?php
    
    $defaultLocales = [
        'af' => 'af-ZA',
        'am' => 'am-ET',
        'as' => 'as-IN',
        'az' => 'az-AZ',
        'ba' => 'ba-RU',
        'be' => 'be-BY',
        'bg' => 'bg-BG',
        'bn' => 'bn-IN',
        'bo' => 'bo-CN',
        'br' => 'br-FR',
        'ca' => 'ca-ES',
        'co' => 'co-FR',
        'cs' => 'cs-CZ',
        'cy' => 'cy-GB',
        'da' => 'da-DK',
        'de' => 'de-DE',
        'el' => 'el-GR',
        'en' => 'en-US',
        'es' => 'es-ES',
        'et' => 'et-EE',
        'eu' => 'eu-ES',
        'fi' => 'fi-FI',
        'fo' => 'fo-FO',
        'fr' => 'fr-FR',
        'fy' => 'fy-NL',
        'ga' => 'ga-IE',
        'gd' => 'gd-IE',
        'gl' => 'gl-ES',
        'gu' => 'gu-IN',
        'he' => 'he-IL',
        'hi' => 'hi-IN',
        'hr' => 'hr-HR',
        'hu' => 'hu-HU',
        'hy' => 'hy-AM',
        'id' => 'id-ID',
        'in' => 'in-ID',
        'is' => 'is-IS',
        'it' => 'it-IT',
        'iw' => 'iw-IL',
        'ja' => 'ja-JP',
        'ka' => 'ka-GE',
        'kk' => 'kk-KZ',
        'kl' => 'kl-GL',
        'km' => 'km-KH',
        'kn' => 'kn-IN',
        'ko' => 'ko-KR',
        'kok' => 'kok-IN',
        'ky' => 'ky-KG',
        'lo' => 'lo-LA',
        'lt' => 'lt-LT',
        'lv' => 'lv-LV',
        'mi' => 'mi-NZ',
        'mk' => 'mk-MK',
        'ml' => 'ml-IN',
        'mn' => 'mn-MN',
        'mr' => 'mr-IN',
        'ms' => 'ms-MY',
        'mt' => 'mt-MT',
        'nb' => 'nb-NO',
        'ne' => 'ne-NP',
        'nl' => 'nl-NL',
        'nn' => 'nn-NO',
        'oc' => 'oc-FR',
        'or' => 'or-IN',
        'pl' => 'pl-PL',
        'ps' => 'ps-AF',
        'pt' => 'pt-PT',
        'ro' => 'ro-RO',
        'ru' => 'ru-RU',
        'rw' => 'rw-RW',
        'sa' => 'sa-IN',
        'si' => 'si-LK',
        'sk' => 'sk-SK',
        'sq' => 'sq-AL',
        'sr' => 'sr-RS',
        'sv' => 'sv-SE',
        'ta' => 'ta-IN',
        'te' => 'te-IN',
        'th' => 'th-TH',
        'tk' => 'tk-TM',
        'tr' => 'tr-TR',
        'tt' => 'tt-RU',
        'uk' => 'uk-UA',
        'ur' => 'ur-PK',
        'uz' => 'uz-UZ',
        'vi' => 'vi-VN',
        'wo' => 'wo-SN',
        'xh' => 'xh-ZA',
        'zh' => 'zh-CN',
        'zu' => 'zu-ZA'
    ];
    
    function getLocaleFromLang($lang) {
        global $defaultLocales;
        return $defaultLocales[$lang] ?? $lang;
    }
    
?>
```

If you have any suggestions on how I might improve it, feel free to comment below!

**[EDIT]**

**An explanation of the criteria I used.**

If you have the Italian it language we can assume it to be it-IT for Italian in Italy. Otherwise, you'd specify it-CH for Italian in Switzerland or it-SM for Italian in San Marino. In this case, it's easy.

English is different. If you apply the same rule, then en-GB would be the default instead of en-US. which should be so IMO, but after decades of having en-US as the default locale for most programs in the IT world, it's only right for this to be true here too.

I'd say half of the "defaults" were on the easy side, but there are also a lot of weird cases where I'm not familiar with the language or the country...
When this happened I had to look up which country had the most amount of native speakers or something else that tied a language to a country of origin if the former solution was inconclusive.

Some cases were hopeless, like ar Arabic. it's such a diffused language spoken in so many countries that I feel there is no point in giving a "default" locale...

**An explanation of why I need this.**

I'm willing to make these "discriminations" because of one reason:
this is only a fallback situation!

In input, I mostly get locales made of language and country codes like en-AU, es-AR, pt-BR, and so on... then, sometimes, there are a few cases where it's only the language code. when this happens some small mechanics break. first of all, the formatting of numbers, values, etc...

It's mainly a contingency for user input, the user has the option to specify a country with the language, but if he doesn't, only the language code gets inserted...
I'm stuck with this mix of full locale codes and language codes and I have to try and fallback on a default locale when only the language is provided so I can try to keep the rest of the code/formatting working as expected by the user!

Hope this clarifies the situation

Answer (score 0):

The rules you describe in your follow-up comment are nothing but your subjective opinion about what countries are "more important" in regards of a given language. You pick Spain arguing Spanish is originally from there, but then pick United States for English (German is not mentioned, but it probably pre-dates Germany itself). You won't find an algorithm for such ruleset, so there's no other way than composing our own hard-coded list. Once you do that, the PHP portion can be as simple as an array lookup:

```
$defaults = [
    'it' => 'it-IT',
    'en' => 'en-US',
    'es' => 'es-ES',
    // ...
];
$requests = [
    'it',
    'it-IT',
    'en-GB',
    'en',
    'es-AR',
    'es-MX',
    'es',
];
foreach ($requests as $input) {
    $output = $defaults[$input] ?? $input;
    echo "$input -> $output\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/pJHWA#v8.2.7)

Comment: yes, I know it can be weird going about assuming the "default" country when missing, but I hoped someone else might have had my same issue in the past and that a solution already existed... I'll just have to manually make my own list along the lines of what you suggested